# Change date format in CSV using PowerShell

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and I have a CSV file where I need to change the format of the dates in 2 columns (as shown in the example below) to the format dd/mm/yyyy.

```
"First Name","Last Name","Employee Number","Course Name","Completion Status","Date_Started","Completion_Date"

Joe,Bloggs,8632,"Test Name",Complete,"26 Nov 2015","26 Nov 2015"
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
Import-Csv D:\temp\test.csv | % {$_.Date_Started = ([datetime]($_.Date_Started)).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy');$_.Completion_Date = ([datetime]($_.Completion_Date)).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy');$_} | Export-Csv 'D:\temp\testBis.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

You can try `[datetime]::ParseExact(...)` to parse special dates.