# Trying to convert date format in all csv files in a directory powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a directory where files are saved daily. I need to convert the format of the date in these files in order to upload them to a program we use. I'm new to Powershell, but I tried this out:

```
$root = "C:\path"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter "logs*.csv"
$convert = ForEach ($file in $files) {
  $csv = Import-Csv $file
  $dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
  ForEach($r in $csv) {
    $r.date = [DateTime]::parse($r.date).ToString($dateFormat) 
  }
  $csv | Export-Csv $root\$file
}
```

I'm getting nothing but an empty file. When I run in debug mode from Powershell ISE I get what I am looking for, which is each file re-saved with the "date" column re-formatted. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of $root\$file, look at the Join-Path cmdlet. Or just use the .FullName property of $file.

Comment: What's the example of current row or for the date field in the source file?

Comment: Also, there is nothing wrong with writing code in the ISE (although I think Visual Studio Code is better) but you should always test your code in a powershell prompt not in the ISE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943712/change-date-format-in-csv-using-powershell see if this helps

Comment: `Export-Csv "$root\$file"`

Comment: Thanks, EBGreen. Using the .FullName property did the trick.