# How can I fix this error when uploading csv data to a SQL Server database with Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv

So I am uploading csv data from a specific file in a folder on my desktop into a SQL Server database using Powershell and some rows will upload just fine however the majority are returning the following error

"Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Conversion failed when converting date
and/or time from character string."
At line:3 char:5

- ```
  $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException"

I know it's an issue converting one of the columns containing a date however I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. Any help is appreciated.
The script is as follows:

````
    # Define variables
$serverName = "TDALYW10"
$databaseName = "ScriptTest"
$tableName = "VehicleStock"
$csvPath = "C:\Users\TDaly\Desktop\PowerShellTest2\vehicleStock.csv"

# Create a new SQL Server connection
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$serverName;Database=$databaseName;Integrated Security=True"

# Open the SQL Server connection
$sqlConnection.Open()

# Create a new SQL Server command
$sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection

# Read the CSV file
$csv = Import-Csv $csvPath

# Loop through each row in the CSV file and insert it into the SQL Server table
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO $tableName (branch, stockNo, reg, category, make, model, variant, buyInSP, purchaseInvDate, dateIn, purchaseInvRef, odometer, clock, qual, [Base & Delivery], Overallowance, WriteDown, Sublet, PDI, Accessory, Bonus, [Motor Tax], [House Charge], Finance, Other, Previous, totalCost, purchaseAmt, purchaseVAT, retail, trade, VRT, VIBE, fuel, cc, body, colour, trim, owners, year, regDate, class, transm, [new/used], daysInStock, lastMOT, nextMOT) VALUES ('$($row.branch)', '$($row.stockNo)', '$($row.reg)', '$($row.category)', '$($row.make)', '$($row.model)', '$($row.variant)', '$($row.buyInSP)', '$($row.purchaseInvDate)', '$($row.dateIn)', '$($row.purchaseInvRef)', '$($row.odometer)', '$($row.clock)', '$($row.qual)', '$($row.'Base & Delivery')', '$($row.Overallowance)', '$($row.WriteDown)', '$($row.Sublet)', '$($row.PDI)', '$($row.Accessory)', '$($row.Bonus)', '$($row.'Motor Tax')', '$($row.'House Charge')', '$($row.Finance)', '$($row.Other)', '$($row.Previous)', '$($row.totalCost)', '$($row.purchaseAmt)', '$($row.purchaseVAT)', '$($row.retail)', '$($row.trade)', '$($row.VRT)', '$($row.VIBE)', '$($row.fuel)', '$($row.cc)', '$($row.body)', '$($row.colour)', '$($row.trim)', '$($row.owners)', '$($row.year)', '$($row.regDate)', '$($row.class)', '$($row.transm)', '$($row.'new/used')', '$($row.daysInStock)', '$($row.lastMOT)', '$($row.nextMOT)')"
    $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

# Close the SQL Server connection
$sqlConnection.Close()
```
````

Comment: *"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."* The error is telling you the problem here; you have an invalid date (and time) value. perhaps it's being stored in an ambiguous date format? Perhaps it really isn't a valid date (such as 2023-02-29 or 2021-19-17). We have no sample data, so we don't know which. *If* it's just ambiguous, you'd likely be better off loading into a staging table, where all/most of your columns are string based data types, and then you can transform the data from that table to the production table.

Comment: See: [Change date format in CSV using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33944143/1701026)

Comment: Apologies, it turns out I was just being an idiot and forgot to correctly set the data type in the SQL table itself. The only issue I'm running into now is when a quotation mark appears in my data for example in the Variant column sometimes there is quotation marks and it is producing the error "Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near 'd'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ', ', ')'."

Comment: this is because you're building the query from raw data. It's usually bad idea, because a file can contain rows with columns like DROP DATABASE oops

Comment: Is there an easy way around this?

Comment: Since you're using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` the _correct_ way is to use parameters with one of the `$sqlCommand.Parameters.Add()` [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add), specifying the correct SQL data type and length to match the columns in the database table. Inserting tainted user data directly into queries as you are is called SQL Injection and leads to [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Or use bulk methods, it's gonna be pretty slow if you use row per row parameter binding / execution

Comment: I understand what you mean yeah however I'm not too familiar with using the parameters command as I am new to powershell. Would something similar to "$sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@branch", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::float)" work except replace the float at the end to match the columns data type in the sql server?

Comment: Thankfully there is only ever around 300 rows per table so speed shouldn't be a huge issue but it's for sure something that a while down the line I'd rather do just to be safe. I was previously using a bulk insert however quickly realised it was causing a lot of issues as the file contains a header row which gave me a lot of bother